# XIB issue with IBOutlet and tag

Tags: objective-c, io, xib

So i have an XIB file which i am trying to use as my application header and call it from different view controllers. The XIB file has two buttons and one label and i have added the file owner to a view controller. I call my XIB file as below line -

```
UIView *appHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ApplicationHeaderViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:appHeaderView];
```

This works perfectly fine. until i add any IBOutlet in my application header view controller. As soon as i add IBOutlet with weak reference the app is crashing with below error method -

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ' setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pageTitle.'
```

I also tried accessing the elements using tags, but still my app crashes with below error -

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Owner should be nil. The outlets you add to the nib should go the the top level view. Not the files owner.

Comment: I tried with owner nil, still its crashing

Comment: you have not problem with outlet and view . you have some problem with pageTitle. please show some code